# Summarizing values from multiple rows to unique rows with same IDs

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to summarize rows with the same ID to one row including values from all columns including NAs.

My dataset looks like this:

```
#    id Date      Red  Green  Blue  Black
#1   1  01-01-21  TRUE NA     NA    NA
#2   1  01-01-21  NA   TRUE   NA    NA
#3   2  05-01-21  TRUE NA     NA    NA       
#4   3  07-01-21  NA   NA     TRUE  NA
#5   3  07-01-21  TRUE NA     NA    NA
#6   3  07-01-21  NA   NA     NA    TRUE
```

My result should look something like this

```
#    id Date      Red  Green  Blue  Black
#1   1  01-01-21  TRUE TRUE   NA    NA
#3   2  05-01-21  TRUE NA     NA    NA       
#4   3  07-01-21  TRUE NA     TRUE  TRUE
```

I already tried the following, but "TRUE" is replaced with "1" and NAs are replaced with "0". Additionally, my "Date" column is erased.

```
test <- test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(Red:Black, ~sum(.x,  na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      Date = c(
        "01.01.2021",
        "01.01.2021",
        "05.01.2021",
        "07.01.2021",
        "07.01.2021",
        "07.01.2021"
      ),
      Red = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA),
      Green = c(NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      Blue = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA),
      Black = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, Date), values_drop_na = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, Date), names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>      id Date       Red   Green Blue  Black
#>   <int> <chr>      <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 01.01.2021 TRUE  TRUE  NA    NA   
#> 2     2 05.01.2021 TRUE  NA    NA    NA   
#> 3     3 07.01.2021 TRUE  NA    TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

or

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>      id Date       Red   Green Blue  Black
#>   <int> <chr>      <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 01.01.2021 TRUE  TRUE  NA    NA   
#> 2     2 05.01.2021 TRUE  NA    NA    NA   
#> 3     3 07.01.2021 TRUE  NA    TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly! how would be the solution if some NAs would additionally be also filled with "FALSE" and I want to keep always the value "TRUE"? in this case a column would not only exist out of one "TRUE" and several "NA" but of one "TRUE" and several "FALSE" and "NA".

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)